# How to join in rails active record using alias

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to convert following SQL into rails active record query

```
"SELECT  * FROM    stocks
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  product_id, MIN(ask_price) min_price
            FROM    stocks
            GROUP   BY product_id,size
        ) sub ON  stocks.product_id = sub.product_id AND
                stocks.ask_price = sub.min_price
                where stocks.product_id = 1"
```

This query fetches the lowest price of the stock group by product and size of product.

So far I have tried to translate it like this it not right.

```
sub_query = Stock.select("product_id, MIN(ask_price) min_price").group(:product_id,:size)
stocks = Stock.joins("#{sub_query} stocks.product_id = sub.product_id AND
                stocks.ask_price = sub.min_price")
```

Comment: You're selecting a lot of redundant data there. A good tip is never use `SELECT *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass into `joins` method all your `join` clause if you want to do some custom joining, like this:

```
stocks = Stock.joins(<<-SQL
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT product_id, MIN(ask_price) min_price
    FROM stocks
    GROUP BY product_id, size
  ) sub ON stocks.product_id = sub.product_id AND stocks.ask_price = sub.min_price
SQL).where(product_id: 1)
```

Comment: I'd change formatting to `stocks = Stock.joins(<<~SQL.squish).where(product_id: 1)` followed by the here document text, instead of having the closing bracket after the whole here document.

Comment: @marek_lipka thank you very for the answer, But isn't it more like inserting raw sql, except for the part .where(product_id: 1) can't we change the inner join query to Active record query.

Comment: @Prem we can't if we want to perform custom `INNER JOIN` query (with nested query) like this. AR can 'automatically' perform only relatively simple `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` queries.